# In VS Code, I'm getting this error, 'Failed to load module. Attempted to load prettier from package.json'

Tags: visual-studio-code, package.json, prettier

When I'm using VS Code and open up a project,  I get this notification in the bottom right corner:

`Failed to load module. If you have prettier or plugins referenced in package.json, ensure you have run`npm install`Attempted to load prettier from package.json.`

`Source: Prettier Code Format (Extension)`

Running npm install doesn't resolve this.  Anyone have any idea why that is or what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Having same issue as well. Are you behind proxy by chance?

Comment: It seems like some path is broken on my machine or something is missing.  We have a package.json with a script to run prettier and a linter.  Running the script from the package.json file doesn't apply prettier but if I format it myself (option+shift+f on a mac) it works.  So bizarre and annoying having to manually format each file.

Comment: This appears to be a fairly recent "addition" to VS Code. Despite using prettier in the past as well, we haven't observed this issue. I don't from which version of VS Code onward this became a problem.

Comment: Having the same issue since a few days ago. No proxy or firewall - something broke prettier in the latest VS Code update

Comment: This is the related github issue. They are looking for more information on this issue (and if available a repo that can be shared). https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/1066

Comment: The `Failed to load module. Attempted to load prettier from package.json.` error notification is highly disturbing and it started after updating to VS Code to version `1.40.1`.

I have shared a solution that involves setting your `Prettier Path` in VS Code Settings

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This is a solution that worked for me

**1.** Install Prettier Globally via npm if you have never installed it globally

```sh
npm i prettier -g
```

**2.** Search & Use the `Prettier Path` Extension Settings in your VS Code Settings

[image]

// You can navigate to VS Code `Settings > Extensions > Prettier` for all Prettier Extension Settings

**3.** Update the `Prettier Path` to your globally installed Prettier.

**For Example**

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prettier` (Mac OS)

`\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prettier` (Windows)

Comment: I've installed Prettier globally.  When I go into VS Code settings, I search for `Prettier Path`.  I see 2 options here, `Prettier:Config Path` and `Prettier: Prettier Path`.  I'm using a mac.  Should i add `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prettier` to both paths or just the first?

Comment: @ghostagent151 just the last one "Prettier: Prettier Path" as per the screenshot.

Comment: Here is another issue I am seeing.  If I download the prettier extension in vs code, I have my settings set up so that on save it automatically applies prettier to my code.  However, there seems to be two different versions of prettier being applied.  If I run `npm run prettier` from the command line, for example, variables that have strings with double quotes are converted to single quotes.  If I save and the auto format is applied, they are converted to double quotes.  Not sure what is happening with that.

Comment: For now, disabling the prettier extension from VS code in workspace settings, lets me run `npm run prettier` from the command line. (This works after having globally installed prettier).  I'm not sure if this is a separate issue, I'll probably need to create a different post and ask there to see why my vs code extension of prettier is applying a different format than my globally installed version.

Comment: @ghostagent151 This is a different issue. Running `npm run prettier` uses the local prettier in your project `node_modules` if a `package.json` exists in the project. My advise is you turn off VS Code `formatOnSave` if you will be using custom formatting rules for your project. To avoid the format overwriting.

Comment: Just want to point out - there is no `Prettier Path` extension. Only `Prettier`. Click on the little gear icon in the bottom right-hand corner after searching for `Prettier`, and configure extension settings. Then scroll down to `Prettier Path` and then add the path `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prettier` for mac or `\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prettier` for Windows.

Comment: Your path to your globally installed modules will differ depending not only on the OS but how you installed npm (i.e nvm, etc). An easy way to get the path is to run `npm root -g`

Comment: In the Devconainer I just pasted the suggested path (written in the VSCode settings)

Comment: This worked for me and I'm on WSL2. I used `npm root -g` as mentioned above to confirm my file path. Pasted the output exactly as is into the Prettier Path VScode settings field.

Comment: Not setting the path worked for me. I had to reset it from VS Code Settings option.

Answer (score 15):

I had prettier installed as a VSCode Extension and this solution worked for me:

I had to remove the Prettier Path in the VSCode settings.
For that click on the coq icon and press reset.

Comment: After two days of searching, this comment helped me. Thanks!

Comment: Same here, this is the only fix that worked, thank you!

Answer (score 13):

If you're on the latest (as of this writing) versions of everything:

VSCode: 1.80

Node: 18

Prettier: 3.0.3

And you're still getting this error, try the solution posted in [this Github Issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/3007#issuecomment-1628836459)

Basically, if you've double checked your paths to global/local Prettier over and over, try adding /index.cjs to the end of the path. This fixed it for me.

-"prettier.prettierPath": "./packages/compiler/node_modules/prettier",

+"prettier.prettierPath": "./packages/compiler/node_modules/prettier/index.cjs",

Comment: This worked incredibly good in my case with a Windows OS machine with a global prettier installation (`C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prettier\index.cjs`), thanks!

Answer (score 8):

In my case i run prettier on WSL Ubuntu and none of the above solutions worked. Downgrading the Prettier VS Code Extension from Version `9.13.0` to `8.2.0` solved the problem for me.

In my case prettier is installed in the project `node_modules` and not globally.

Comment: I have the same environment as you.
This is a new [issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/3020#issuecomment-1584068844) with vscode 1.79.0
There is another easier workaround:
* create / add to your project's lolcal .vscode/settings.json
* this config: "prettier.prettierPath": "./node_modules/prettier"

Comment: @Getsuga your fix actually worked best in my use case as I'm working with Astro which uses it's own prettier config so installing globally didn't work for me

Comment: @Getsuga you should promote your comment to an answer, as it fixed this problem for me today. Also, it's annoying to have to tell prettier where it is.

Comment: Update from me: the fix by @Getsuga stopped working for me (for an unknown reason). I downgraded my VS code prettier extension to v9.13.0 from the latest version and it now works again

Comment: Downgrading to 9.13.0 worked for me.

Comment: Downgrading to 9.13.0 worked for me too.

Answer (score 3):

When setting up Prettier it is important to configure it per-project. Not every project uses the same code style, thus it is important to respect the style of whatever project you are currently working in.

The demo repo `bahmutov/prettier-config-example` has two subfolders, each with its distinct code style, enforced by Prettier. In reality, each of your repos will have its style; I am using subfolders in order to keep the example simple.

`npm install --save-dev --save-exact prettier`

Comment: Is `--save-exact` truly necessary here? Also, +1 for **explicit* install/setup. Global/implicit setup and assumptions will be impactful when you forget that it's out there.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

It now works for me with `prettier-vscode` 4.1.1 and `prettier` 2.0.4, give it a try. I can either use the bundled or locally installed version of prettier.

[Notable changes](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

- [4.0.0] Updated prettier to 2.0
- [4.1.0] Added configuration option withNodeModules to enable processing of files in the node_modules folder [default: false]
- [4.1.0] Support loading Prettier from node_modules even if it doesn't appear as a direct dependency in a package.json

---

#### Original post

I encountered this problem when inspecting the source code of an external package under `node_modules`.

A workaround is to remove the `prettier` entry in `package.json` of this package - no local/global `prettier` install necessary. [Example](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/2.4.0/package.json#L50):

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "prettier": "^1.19.1", // remove this line completely
  },
}
```

Keep the `package.json` valid - no trailing comma, don't just comment the line out. The reason why it works is:

> The extension searches the tree down until we file a package.json. If that package.json contains prettier, the extension uses that, otherwise it will fall back to using the bundled version of prettier. [Link](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/1066#issuecomment-557821961)

My guess is, that the extension wants to use `prettier` from the package, even if it is `devDependencies`.

There should be no harm to drop the `devDependency` from a package in `node_modules`. This also makes it possible to use the `prettier` version bundled with `prettier-vscode` (no install necessary).

Answer (score 2):

Tried all the solutions provided in here, didn't help.
Updating Visual Studio Code fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2):

What @tunji-oyeniran said worked for me.
I installed prettier globally, like he said:

```
npm i prettier -g
```

Then I looked inside my computer to find it

[image]

I saw using pwd command that the path is correct, then I moved to vscode and I looked for that extinsion path:

[image]

I restarted the vscode and I saw that formating code is working.

This si my settings.json:

```
{
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "editor.fontSize": 12,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
    "[javascript]": {
        // "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnPaste": true
    },
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "editor.columnSelection": false,
    "explorer.compactFolders": false,
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    // "javascript.format.enable": true,
    "prettier.prettierPath": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prettier",
}
```

The prettier path was added automatically here, in this settings.json.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same problem and tried all the steps above without a solution. My Prettier vscode extension was ignoring config files in the end.

For me the issue was with the Prettier extension in Visual Studio Code, as it fails to locate the local .prettierrc configuration file even when it exists... Although you can attempt to set the file path manually at settings, the extension continuously defaults to the Visual Studio Code settings. Therefore, the simplest solution is to add the following line to the .vscode/settings.json file: "prettier.configPath": ".prettierrc".
To make sure, just add this complete config file:

```
{   
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",   
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,   
  "editor.formatOnPaste": false,   
  "prettier.useEditorConfig": false,   
  "prettier.useTabs": false,   
  "prettier.configPath": ".prettierrc" 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this and discovered I had a syntax error in my package.json file. There was a trailing comma on one line, and that alone seemed to be the root cause for me.

I noticed this because I saw the following output when trying to run some Angular tests:

```
C:\... [feature/migrate-away-from-angular-http +2 ~6 -0 | +0 ~5 -0 !]> ng test
10% building 3/3 modules 0 active20 11 2019 21:11:18.638:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
20 11 2019 21:11:19.575:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v4.1.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
20 11 2019 21:11:19.576:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
20 11 2019 21:11:19.594:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome

ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.spec.ts
Module not found: SyntaxError: C:\...\package.json (directory description file): SyntaxError: C:\...\package.json (directory description file): SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 167
 @ ./src/app/app.component.spec.ts 7:31-75
 @ ./src sync \.spec\.ts$
 @ ./src/test.ts
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Alternative Solution (without global installation of prettier)

If you have a project with a locally installed prettier (e.g. via `npm install -D prettier`), you don't want to add it globally.

Maybe you just clicked "Do not allow" when VSCode asked you, if you want to allow a local installation of prettier run with the installed extension.

In that case, the solution is:

1. Open VSCode and type `cmd + shift + p` to open the Command Palette.
2. Type `Prettier: Reset Module Execution State`
3. Then just save your file again and VSCode will ask you, if you want to allow to run prettier. There you want to select `Allow everywhere`.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

> Preferences -> Settings

Search for

> prettier path

In the below option write the name of the prettier file:

> Prettier: Prettier Path

> Path to the prettier module

I have .prettierrc as the file name.

Here is an example file .prettierrc:

```
{
    "useTabs": true,
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "printWidth": 120
}
```

**Solution 2**
There is some strange and complex setup / configuration for prettier which I cannot figure out. Therefore, to format the files using prettier I use the command:

> yarn --cwd /path/to/folder run format

Comment: Solution 1 worked for me, did not even need to restart anything, it picked it up right away.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by doing `npm install` globally.

I had this issue when I cleaned my `node_nodules`. I had `eslint` along with prettier globally installed. And when I deleted the `node_modules` this error stated showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the path or leave it as empty. It worked in M1 mac

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to specify the `index.cjs` file. So the prettier path ended up being:

`/node_modules/prettier/index.cjs`

Feels like the extension should figure that out automatically, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

## Yarn PnP Enabled? Try This.

My issue was having enabled PnP in Yarn. This command fixed it for me (from the command line):

### `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`

VSCode couldn't resolve prettier inside of `node_modules` since that folder doesn't exist when PnP is enabled. The fix was super easy, as described in [Yarn's documentation on Editor SDKs](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks).

### From Yarn Docs: [Editor SDKs](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks)

"Smart IDEs (such as VSCode or IntelliJ) require special configuration for TypeScript to work when using Plug'n'Play installs."

This script installed and configured a bunch of files in my `.yarn` directory, and immediately solved my issues. Check out the links above to read more.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77124000/5501739) worked for me. However, I have `prettier` only installed locally in the project.

Curiously once it was working, I could remove the path (which was previously blank) and it has continued to work even after restarting the OS.

Answer (score -1):

disable the **prettier** extension then enable it again then
Reload **vscode** with :
`Developer: Reload window`, fix the problem for me