# Prettier not getting configured in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, prettier

I am not able to configure "Prettier" into my VS Code.
I followed the following steps:

1. Installed Prettier and selected Prettier as the 'Default Formatter' for both User and Workspace.
2. Installed node js.
3. Ran the command `npm install`.
4. Ran the command `npm i prettier -g`.
5. Extracted the prettier path `npm root -g`.
6. Added the path '\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prettier' to the prettier path as is mentioned in the following solution in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866847/in-vs-code-im-getting-this-error-failed-to-load-module-attempted-to-load-pr".
7. Added the permission 'Format on Save' in the VS code.

But now I am receiving this error ["ERROR" - 4:16:59 pm] Error loading node module '\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prettier'
["ERROR" - 4:16:59 pm] Cannot find module '\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prettier'.

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.